# How to specify year only as a datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms-2012

I'm creating a table and want to store one field as date datatype. However I only want to store the year and not additional info (ie: month, day, or time.)

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Project
(ProjectID int not null identity(1,1) unique
,PreviousYear1 date                         -- I need this format: (YYYY)
)
```

Any suggestions on how to store a year only date data-type? I'm working in ssms -2012. My aim is to accomplish this without later having to convert the datatype or alter it to only show year.

Comment: so you just need an INT column?

Comment: In Sql-server-2008 if u want to store the datetime data it will be saved in 'year-month-day hour:min:sec.milliSec' format only.So either int or varchar.No choice to store only year in datetime field.

Comment: @user1221684 Not specifically but from the answer below I'm guessing that you're suggesting I store the years as an int value?

Comment: why not.. you can even use a SMALLINT

Comment: A DateTime must have all components.   Even if you enter with no time it goes in a as midnight and you must specify month and day.

Comment: @User1221684 What you are suggest will work for my needs, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL below will show you how to use a check constraint to do this (update the year range as per your requirements):

```
CREATE TABLE Project
  (
    ProjectID int not null identity(1,1) unique,
    PreviousYear1 int 

    CONSTRAINT CHK_PreviousYear1_validity 

    CHECK (PreviousYear1 > 1900 and len(PreviousYear1) = 4)                     
  )
```

Comment: Instead of `(PreviousYear1 > 1900 and len(PreviousYear1) = 4)` you can simply use `(PreviousYear1  BETWEEN 1901 AND 9999)`. It's faster and more clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Project
(ProjectID int not null identity(1,1) unique
,PreviousYear1 smallint   
 CONSTRAINT CHK_PreviousYear1_validity 
   CHECK (PreviousYear1 >= 1000 and PreviousYear1 <= 9999)                       
)
```

smallint goes up to 32,767
So you would use a update and insert trigger to limit to 1000 - 9999
Or more likely  1900 - 9999

Check constraint is a better answer
I borrowed from Roit, give that the check

Answer (score 0):

You should use an INT data type and put some check constraints on the table to enforce reasonable values, like no negative numbers and such.  The Date data type is exactly that, a complete date.

Answer (score -2):

We can't, but you could use:

```
CREATE TABLE Project(
    ProjectID int not null identity(1,1) unique
    ,PreviousYear1 VARCHAR(4) -- To save the year only, INT it's better ;)
)
```

When you'll save a record just put a string with the year :)

```
INSERT INTO Project(PreviousYear1) VALUES ('1994'),('2015')
```

Comment: How about INSERT INTO Project(PreviousYear1) VALUES ('bad'),('miss')

Comment: The logic tier takes care about that ;)

Comment: It is tagged SQL.    Why in the world would you store a year in VARCHAR(4) ?

Comment: The guy wants to store a year, but in Transact SQL is not possible do this with a default datatype, but he can use a VARCHAR or an INT or a UINT or SMALLINT, etc. VARCHAR(4) is just an example :)

Comment: VARCHAR(4) is an example that does NOT restrict it to a 4 digit year.  And there is no UNIT in SQL.

Comment: Ignore UINT XD and yes VARCHAR(4) is an example that does not restrict it to a 4 digit year :)